# Amazon Web Services Free Trial: query about get and put requests

Tags: amazon-s3, google-app-engine

Amazon recently introduced a free tier for its cloud offering. I signed up for AWS and while signing up for the free tier of S3, i found this

> As part of AWS Free Usage Tier, you
>   can get started with Amazon S3 for
>   free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers
>   receive 5 GB of Amazon S3 storage,
>   **20,000 Get Requests, 2,000 Put Requests,**
>   15GB of bandwidth in and
>   15GB of bandwidth out each month for
>   one year.

source:aws.amazon.com , emphasis mine.

20,000 GET requests & 2000 puts mean , 20,000 page views(max) and 2000 file uploads per month.

Isn't that lower than what App Engine offers [43,200,000 requests](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html) per day.Am I missing some thing, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

Google Apps engine costs less. So if you can live with the restrictions (programming model!) of app engine, it is the **by far** more cost effective solution.

Comment: that means that aws free tier will only offer 20k page views per month?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is only true if you are hosting a static website directly from S3.  The free tier also includes the micro instance; and that will have EBS storage that you can use to host the site.

The uploads could be handled there too.

BTW: I'm not disputing that App-engine isn't cheaper.  If its paradigm works for you, it almost certainly is less expensive.

Comment: I didn't know that. Using appengine means developing an from scratch to meet appengine's requirements, which is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Google's "programming model" is designed for speed. Amazon simply cannot compete in this space because of old-school architectural design.